# Image representation in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

```
Mat img=imread("image_location");
```

I studied that 'img' variable is like an object reference variable in java which refers the original object(an image in this case).
Out of curiosity i thought to find out what the 'img' variable holds.If it refers to the actual object,it should hold an address and return the address when i use

```
cout<<img;
```

But,Shock,it is returning the actual image(pixel values) to the output.
I think there is something wrong with my understanding.
Plz help,I'm a noob programmer who's trying to make my brain understand these concepts.

Comment: Yes, better improve first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::Mat` holds the data representing the image in an array, plus other data specific to the `cv::Mat` instance. The data array itself depends on the image's format. You can have different numbers of channels and channel depth, and when you use `imread` you can pass a second parameter that gives you some control over this. So `cv::Mat` does not have a pointer to the original object, it has a pointer to an array containing data representing that object.

On top of that, in newer versions of OpenCV, the `ostream& operator<<` is overloaded for `cv::Mat`, and that tries to produce a nice printout of the array values in matrix format. This is what you see when you `std::cout << someMat;`

Comment: so when ever 'cout' sees a cv::Mat variable(which contains the information about the actual image),it will call a method which prints the actual image(pixel values).is that right??

Comment: @tez that seems to be the case, although I think it may print out all the channels for multi-channel images.

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused by the overloading of `operator<<` for the `cv::Mat`.

Comment: so when ever 'cout' sees a cv::Mat variable(which refers the image),it will call a method which prints the actual image(pixel values).is that right??

Answer (score 0):

The Mat object contains a pointer to the data, but it also contains other values. See the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat) for more information.